# Replacement in excel sheet by list

Tags: regex, vba, excel

How to make bulk replacement using regexp patterns from excel range, see my answer below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my way to make replacement in Excel range using list from another range based on RegExp:

```
Sub regexpreplace()
Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A1000") 'range in which we make replace
Set regrange = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B6") 'range with RegExp pattern
'in range C1:C6 we have pattern for replace

    For Each D In regrange

        For Each C In Myrange
            Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
            rgx.IgnoreCase = True
            rgx.Pattern = D.Value
            rgx.Global = True
            C.Value = rgx.Replace(C.Value, D.Offset(0, 1).Value)
        Next

    Next
End Sub
```

In this code:

- A1:A1000 - range with input values
- B1:B6 - list of RegExp patterns
- C1:C6 - list of output patterns

Some examples of using script:
[image]